# What is the magento url for posting SOAP request

Tags: magento, soap

Below is my code

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
using(var response = wc.OpenRead("http://templatebar.com/QA/performancetesting/enterprise1_10_0_2/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1"))
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response);
    string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
var loginRequest = string.Format(XElement.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"XMLFiles\login.xml").ToString(),"apikey","apipassword");var loginRequest = string.Format(XElement.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"XMLFiles\login.xml").ToString(),"admin","abcd.1234");
var response1 = wc.UploadString("", loginRequest);
```

My question is what should be the "address" in UploadString function so that the login request gets the desired result i.e,Magento Session id

If I use this "http://templatebar.com/QA/performancetesting/enterprise1_10_0_2/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1" 
URL again then I get the list of wsdl services available,which is the same as in response variable.

Please Help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the provided wsdl, the endpoint location is: http://templatebar.com/QA/performancetesting/enterprise1_10_0_2/magento/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/

(source: check the wsdl:service location for it. The url is written in the location-element)